# .dds File Loses Color When Viewed in Layers

Tags: color, gimp, layers, file-format, blender

I have three .dss photo files from a video game that are textures. A lot of the separate maps (diffuse/specular/normal) are on different layers of these photos so I need some layers individually to use them. I'm using these textures in conjunction with Blender 3D.

When the .dss files are not changed they contain color. Viewing one with Blender only showed the Alpha layer, but it was in color. After opening these files in Gimp and proceeding to decompose them (Color > Components > Decompose) to RGBA, all the layers were available. But when viewing the .dss layers individually there was no color and saving them to .png kept the lack of color. How do I keep the color intact when accessing separate layers?

Comment: This is what *Color > Components > Decompose* does, by definition. 

It takes the three (or 4 in case of alpha) channels and separates them into separate greyscale layers representing the amount of red, green, and blue in various parts of the image. You can recombine the layers into a color image, but I'm not really sure what you are trying to do..

Comment: So to be more specific, the maps were contained in a file structure like this (http://cdn1.eveonline.com/community/devblog/2010/TexturePack_large.jpg). (The one on the left). That exact structure has changed, but is still very similar. To 3D render the models I need some of the maps that are contained in the images.

Comment: I must be missing something.. From your question it sounds like you already managed to separate the RGBA channels into different images. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: Well, it's weird. Look at that image again (left side). The first photo has the 3 diffuse images on the RGB layers, and the glow map on the A layer. When I open this image in gimp normally, I will only see the A layer, and in color. When I decompose, I can see each layer individually, but none of them have color, including the A layer.

Comment: To add even more confusion, when composing the image immediately after decomposing it, I can now see all the layers at once, and in color.

Comment: I'm not sure why end up with separate layers for each channel after composing again, but I'm not really clear on why you are expecting/want color on the decomposed layers in the first place. Do you want the red channel to appear red instead of grey? What for?

Comment: meed96, what you are describing is the expected result of the Decompose filter. Please provide some screenshots of what you're seeing, and tell us why you expect a different result.

Comment: I'm just confused why it's behaving the way it is. Here's some screenshots. So this is what it looks like when I open it in Gimp, no changes. (http://imgur.com/34RDa1e) Here's what all the layers look like after decomposition (note, all layers are selected but the red color I should be seeing doesn't exist). (http://imgur.com/4hvebQb) That layer is the red layer, and it's completely greyscale. Wouldn't I only be seeing red on the red layer?

Comment: No. What you see is the values of the red component of the pixels. That is a single value in the range of 0-255 and thus represented as a greyscale value. Coloring those layers wouldn't help you to visualize the result. Recompose will, and real-time recomposition will do even more; that is something  to expect for GIMP 3.0